# Field in oracle table updated as null during resource busy scenario

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g

This is one negative case.

This is pseudocode of my plsql code

```
SELECT marks into v_marks from table_a;

SELECT ROLLNO into v_rollno from table_b;

Update table_a set marks = marks- var1  where id=1;

commit;
```

This plsql code is running in one process (Process A). I am just changing the values in the table_b with some other Process B(TOAD). I am just failing to give a commit in toad(Process B).

Now if my Process A executes then it will be waiting at Line 2 to acquire a resource.

Process A still waiting to acquire a resource...

Now if i give commit then both process will be come to end.

The problem i am facing is marks in table a is updated as null after both process completes.

I cannot explain this sceneario more better. But curious to know why it is updated as NULL?

Comment: From the pseudocode there is no block; writers don't block readers, so updating `table_b` in one session doesn't affect a query against that table in any other session. But you also aren't using `v_marks` or `v_rollno` in your update, and as written you're updating `marks` based on itself - so if it was already null it would remain null. Can you update the question with a consistent, and preferably recreatable, scenario?

Comment: Also, if `var1` is null, `marks-var1` is null as well.

Comment: @a1ex07 var1 is declared as integer. is it can be null? I am belogs to c++ platform. In my language it will not be null. It can be either 0 or junk

Comment: @VinothKumar - it isn't clear if `var1` is a column or a PL/SQL variable, but either way, yes it can be null by default. I assume it's PL/SQL, in which case [see the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/fundamentals.htm#sthref81): "In a variable declaration, the initial value is optional unless you specify the NOT NULL constraint" and "If you do not specify an initial value for a variable, assign a value to it before using it in any other context". If you haven't assigned a value to `var1` or set a default it will be null.

Comment: @AlexPoole It is plsql variable. It helped me out